# htaccess rewrite of URL with $_GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I rewrite:

```
http://www.domain.com?parama=1&paramb=1
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule http://www.domain.com?parama=1&paramb=1 http://www.domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Are you permanently redirecting (bad link on google etc) or displaying `http://www.domain.com?parama=1&paramb=1` as index?

Comment: Stopping hacker attack until I can get stronger measures in place

Comment: Ok, let's stop them together. What is the problem, what are params a and b exactly?