# Htaccess rewrite URL with passing $_GET parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have been trying to attain a particular result with the display of URLs within a directory. I have referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587225/htaccess-rewrite-of-url-with-get-parameters) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052357/url-rewriting-with-htaccess-not-passing-parameter) post. I'm working on a project in PHP. Currently, my URL with parameters is the following:

`https://subdomain.example.com/Dir/childDir/?id=12345` OR `https://subdomain.example.com/Dir/childDir/index.php?id=12345`

The result I am looking for is
`https://subdomain.example.com/Dir/childDir/12345`

I can take care of error handling in PHP (i.e. mandatory parameter, else redirect), but Htaccess has always gone over my head. Currently, this is my Htaccess for the dir.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^childDir\/([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?$ index.php?method=$1
```

=====================================

Edit: Solved. Thank you [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225)

```
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite /Dir/childDir/12345 to /Dir/childDir/index.php?id=12345
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Result:
[image: Working example]

`<? echo $_GET['id'] ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this rule in your `Dir/childDir/.htaccess`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite /Dir/childDir/12345 to /Dir/childDir/index.php?id=12345
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: There's no way to have this in the child directory? It must be in the parent?

Comment: Sure that can be done. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Works effing flawlessly. Thank you.